# Why doesn't my node publish to the topic cmd_vel?

Tags: navigation, spin, spinonce, publisher, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm trying to send commands to an Ardrone through cmd_vel topic. But I don't know why it isn't working, here is my code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <sensor_msgs/image_encodings.h>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Twist.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/Point.h>
#include <std_msgs/Empty.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int posY,posZ;
float ey,ez,ex,dey,eypa,dex,expa,dez,ezpa,iex,iey,iez,uy,ux,uz,posX;
geometry_msgs::Twist twist_msg;
geometry_msgs::Point point_msg;
std_msgs::Empty emp_msg;

    void posCallback(const geometry_msgs::Point& msg)
    {
        ros::NodeHandle neu;
        ros::Rate loop_rate(50);
        posY=msg.x;
        posZ=msg.y;
        posX=msg.z;
        //printf("[%d,%d,%f] \n",posY,posZ,posX);
        ros::Publisher pub_twist= neu.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 1);

        ey=(319-posY)/320.0;
        ez=(179-posZ)/180.0;
        ex=(40.0-posX)/40.0;
        dey=-(ey-eypa)/1.0;
        dez=-(ez-ezpa)/1.0;
        dex=-(ex-expa)/1.0;
        iey=iey+ey;
        iez=iez+ez;
        iex=iex+ex;
        uy=ey+dey;
        ux=ex/4+dex;
        uz=ez+dez;
        if(abs(uy)>1.0)
        {
            uy=uy/abs(uy);              
        }
        if(abs(ux)>1.0)
        {
            ux=ux/abs(ux);              
        }
        if(abs(uz)>1.0)
        {
            uz=uz/abs(uz);              
        }
        twist_msg.angular.z=uy;
        twist_msg.linear.x=ux;
        //ROS_INFO("Ball Position:[%f,%f,%f,%f]",ex,dex,iex,ux);                            
        pub_twist.publish(twist_msg);
        ros::spinOnce();
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //Initializing ROS
    ros::init(argc, argv, "control");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Rate loop_rate(50);    

    twist_msg.linear.y=0.0;
    twist_msg.linear.x=0.0;
    twist_msg.linear.z=0.0;
    twist_msg.angular.z=0.0;
    twist_msg.angular.y=0.0;
    twist_msg.angular.x=0.0;

    eypa=0.0;
    expa=0.0;
    ezpa=0.0;
    iex=0.0;
    iey=0.0;
    iez=0.0;
        
    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("color_position", 100, posCallback);
    ros::spin();
}
```

The idea is that the node subscribe to color_tracking topic, and gets the reference, then with that reference it computes a pid controler, and send it to the drone via cmd_vel. But when i echo cmd_vel, it doesnt gets anything
Again I think is a problem of spin() and spinOnce(), but i have no idea.
Hope someone can help me, thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212903/why-doesn%27t-my-node-publish-to-the-topic-cmd_vel?/) by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2015-07-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You instantiate a new publisher everytime your callback posCallback is called. There is a time gap between instantiating a publisher till a publish call to it actually publishes, as things are threaded behind the scenes. So what happens everytime your posCallback is called:

- Publisher pub_twist gets instantiated
- publish() is called on the instantiated pub_twist publisher at the end of your callback. The publisher is not set up correctly yet at that point in time, so nothing actually gets published.
- pub_twist goes out of scope and it's
  destructor is called as it is a local
  variable of your posCallback.

What you can do is make the Publisher a global variable and use it. Minimal example:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
[...]

ros::Publisher pub_twist;

[...]
    void posCallback(const geometry_msgs::Point& msg)
    {
        [...]
        pub_twist.publish(twist_msg);
    }

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    [...] 

    pub_twist= nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("/cmd_vel", 1);

    ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("color_position", 100, posCallback);
    ros::spin();
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-07-05**:
I tried your solution, but it shows me this error:
call to publish() on an invalid publisher
I think its because i dont do the advertise stuff in the callback function but in the main, then it doesnt configure correctly the publisher.
Any idea?

**Comment by [erivera1802](https://answers.ros.org/users/22029/erivera1802/) on 2015-07-05**:
I writed the code again and your solution worked perfectly! Thank you Stefan